# Why does onTap and functions in it does not work in InkWell?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm trying to open link when tapped on ListWheelScrollView, but it doesn't work. It doesn't even enter the OnTap

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:string_validator/string_validator.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class News extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map news;

  @override
  _NewsState createState() => _NewsState();

  const News({Key key, this.news}) : super(key: key);
}

class _NewsState extends State<News> {
  Map test;
  double textPadding = 290;

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  launchURL(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url, forceWebView: true);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    test = (ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments);
    var fixedTest = test['data'].news4today;

    checkUrls() {
      for (int i = 0; i < fixedTest.length; i++) {
        if (fixedTest[i]['urlToImage'] == null ||
            !isURL(fixedTest[i]['urlToImage'])) {
          fixedTest[i]['urlToImage'] =
              'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8a/eb/d8/8aebd875fbddd22bf3971c3a7159bdc7.png';
        }
        if (fixedTest[i]['url'] == null || !isURL(fixedTest[i]['url'])) {
          fixedTest[i]['url'] = 'https://google.com';
        }
      }
    }

    checkUrls();

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(child: Text('News')),
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
        ),
        body: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
            itemExtent: 400,
            diameterRatio: 9,
            squeeze: 1.2,
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
              // debugPrint(index.toString());
            },
            childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
                childCount: 100,
                builder: (context, index) => Container(
                      child: Stack(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Material(
                            child: InkWell(
                              onDoubleTap: () {
                                launchURL(fixedTest[index]['urlToImage']);
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                height: 353.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                                      image: NetworkImage(
                                          fixedTest[index]['urlToImage'])),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 285),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                  child: Text(
                                fixedTest[index]['title'],
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                maxLines: 4,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              )),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.purple[100],
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.8),
                                  spreadRadius: 1,
                                  blurRadius: 3,
                                  offset: Offset(1, 1),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ))));
  }
}
```

I was trying to remove Containers with Ink, but if I'll do that, it will ruin the app because of the text margin. Tried onDoubleTap too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using inkwell you should use the RichText widget for tap-able text. Below is the code for the same. Using regular text and inkwell is not a good practice specially because if you want to add a regular text and a link right after it you will have to use Row widget and if the links goes to next next line it won't look as expected.

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';


new RichText(
      text: new TextSpan(text: 'Non touchable. ', children: [
        new TextSpan(
          text: 'Tap here.',
          recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = () => print('Tap Here onTap'),
        )
      ]),
    );
```

About your error, instead of yor launchURL function, try printing something to know if the double tap gesture is recognized or not. If you are getting the print statement on double tap, then its an error in your launchURL function.

Comment: I have a problem, it doesn't print Tap here... at all when i click on it.

Comment: Ok wait I'll test your code and come back to you

Comment: I just checked it and it's an issue with the widget provided by Flutter themselves. You can try using this package as a workaround : https://pub.dev/packages/clickable_list_wheel_view

Comment: Okay, i will try it later. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`InkWell` must have `Material` parent. Wrap your `InkWell` in `Material` widget.
See `InkWell` [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html).
Also if `launchURL(fixedTest[index]['url'])` is an async function which you have to `await` this function halt your app until completion.

Comment: Tried wrapping it with Material(), no response still

Comment: Can you add to answer function code? Or delete it and test print without it?

Comment: Updated. Sorry if the code is smelly, I'm only studying.

Comment: No worries, try to use it with `await` appended like in code below

Comment: I can't understand how should i use await there. It says "The await expression can only be used in an async function. ", because it is in return Scaffold()

Comment: You are right. My bad. Your `test` value is not null? Arguments passed as expected?

Comment: yes, everything is fine, data is not empty